# Getting error while implementing Tab Navigator in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tabnavigator, react-navigation-bottom-tab

Trying to create a BottomTabNavigtor in a React Native Application. This is my Navigator Code.

```
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { Platform } from "react-native";

import CategoriesScreen from "../screens/CategoriesScreen";
import CategoryMealScreen from "../screens/CategoryMealScreen";
import MealDetailScreen from "../screens/MealDetailScreen";
import FavoritesScreen from "../screens/FavoritesScreen";
import Colors from "../constants/colors";

const MealsNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Categories: {
      screen: CategoriesScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Meal Categories"
      }
    },
    CategoryMeals: {
      screen: CategoryMealScreen
    },  MealDetail: MealDetailScreen
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? Colors.primaryColor : ''
      },
      headerTintColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'white' : Colors.primaryColor
    },
  }
);

const MealsFavTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Meals: MealsNavigator,
  Favorites: FavoritesScreen
});

export default createAppContainer(MealsFavTabNavigator);
```

Following a course for this application. Getting this error:

> TypeError: (0, _native.createNavigatorFactory) is not a function.
>   (In '(0, _native.createNavigatorFactory)(BottomTabNavigator)',
>   '(0, _native.createNavigatorFactory)' is undefined)

Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well if you're using latest release of react-navigation, lots of things have changed:

> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html

Now you have to use this syntax :

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```